# FluentValidation: How to inject all registered validators?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, startup, fluentvalidation

I'm using **FluentValidation.AspNetCore** library (Version="10.3.3") for a .Net Core project.

To register validators i use this:
`services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<TestValidator>();`

For example i have class called *Test* and i can inject validator for this class like this:

```
    public class Service : IService
    {
        private readonly IValidator<Test> _testValidator;

        public Service(IValidator<Test> testValidator)
        {
            _testValidator = testValidator;
        }
   }
```

But i dont know how to inject all registered validators into my Service constructor as IEnumerable instance. So what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: If you really need all of them, the Service is doing too much... but anyhow: you could probably work around this with a factory.

Comment: Did you try injecting `IEnumerable<IValidator<Test>>`?

Comment: @Steven Yes. With such way i will only get validator instances which inherit IValidator<Test> but assembly contains other validators for different instances.

Comment: @Fildor I use service as Decorator for validating requests and responses. And i have assembly which contains validators for models that belongs to service. That's why i want to get all of them. Maybe factory is the way if there is no other opportunities.

Comment: So you want to inject an `IEnumerable<IValidator<object>>` and have that list contain all registered validators. That's impossible due to the 'limitations' of the .NET's type system. This has to do with how [variance and contra-variance](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/) works. Instead of injecting all validators, you can instead try to inject some sort of mediator implementation that resolves the required validators on the fly from the `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: @Steven Tnx for answer. I will check the solution with mediator.

Comment: I am using Version="11.3.0" of FluentValidation, is there anyway I can inject all of my validators in constructor because i do not really understand the solution that @Guru Stron gave.

Comment: @Jbtf what exactly you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FluentValidation`'s `AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining` registers all validators [implementing `IValidator<T>`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/f72713fe89cb96ed2371608a8c3fad0aecbb35b1/src/FluentValidation/AssemblyScanner.cs#L71) from assembly as [generic interface and self](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/f72713fe89cb96ed2371608a8c3fad0aecbb35b1/src/FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L90) so you can resolve them only by concrete type or constructed generic (i.e. `IValidator<Test>`) i.e. it is not possible to resolve all of them as a single collection.

If you really want you can try leveraging that `IValidator<T>` inherits `IValidator` and use the following (a bit hacky) solution:

```cs
services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(Val1));

// Only after all validators registrations
var serviceDescriptors = services
    .Where(descriptor => typeof(IValidator) != descriptor.ServiceType
           && typeof(IValidator).IsAssignableFrom(descriptor.ServiceType)
           && descriptor.ServiceType.IsInterface)
    .ToList();

foreach (var descriptor in serviceDescriptors)
{
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(IValidator),
        p => p.GetRequiredService(descriptor.ServiceType),
        descriptor.Lifetime));
}
```

After that you will be able to resolve `IEnumerable<IValidator>`. Though not sure that this will be much help for you.